# MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When I type `node server.js` it returns me this error

```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/islam/workspace/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:327:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/islam/workspace/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:274:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/islam/workspace/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:177:49)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1283:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

**

When I type in command line `mongod` it returns me this

```
    2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=24805 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=user
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.4
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 888390515874a9debd1b6c5d36559ca86b44babd
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

**

However the `mongo` command gives me this error

```
 MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-05-05T23:34:21.724+0600 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-05-05T23:34:21.724+0600 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

---

I need to access to my database collections,

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo by default writes data to /data folder and the user who is running mongo service does not have permission to create /data folder.

You can get this information from this log snippet

```
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2017-05-05T23:33:06.816+0600 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
```

So, you need to do this

```
sudo mkdir /data/db
sudo chown $USER -R /data/db # give permission to the user who is running mongo service
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to create the /data/db folder

try doing this in the terminal

`sudo mkdir /data/db`

then start mongodb

Comment: where? In my project folder? please can you explain it more specific?

Comment: No it would be in the root directory of your machine. If you just open the terminal and type in the command just like I have it in my answer from any directory it will work

Answer (score 0):

first run **mongod.exe** If it gives any warnings regarding unsafe shutdowns, metrics, diagnostics ignore them and run **mongo.exe** in **another** CLI(command line Interface).

Even then if it does not work, just backup the **../data/db** directories and redo the database.

Before access the db using a database driver(eg: mongoose,mongojs) make sure that the database is up and running.

$ mongo 
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.4
use YourAwesomeDatabaseName
switched to db YourAwesomeDatabaseName

You are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue /mongo.js:237:13 in local terminal trying to run GCP-hosted mongo. I fixed it by removing tags in GCP

Answer (score 0):

hey there This is the issue because of your mongodb server is not running

you can verify this by

> sudo service mongodb status

**
you need to start the server by running command

> **sudo service mongodb start**

Good Luck